# Detecting Mobile Device connected by usb in Adobe Air for desktop

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air, usb, detect

I want to Detect the connected mobile device in my adobe air app.
Have tried using Capabilities class but in vain...any leads?

Comment: What is the mobile device connected to? Where is the AIR app running (on the mobile device or on the desktop?) How did you try to use the Capabilities class?

Comment: You won't be able to do that out of the box for sure. Your best bet will probably be developing a native ANE with desired functionality. In any case, not a trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we do this in one of our company's development tools, but it takes a bit of work (and some installed software); not sure if it is something you can use in your app.

If you have the Adobe AIR SDK on your computer, there are two command line commands you can run to detect connected iOS or Android devices:
`{INSERT-AIR-SDK-PATH-HERE}\bin\adt.bat -devices -platform ios`
`{INSERT-AIR-SDK-PATH-HERE}\bin\adt.bat -devices -platform android`

You can run these commands from an Air app on Windows by using the NativeProcess class. Then you can parse the output of these commands to determine if a device is connected. If you run these commands repeatedly based on a timer, then you can continually detect if a device is connected or disconnected :)

NOTE: Running the command for detecting iOS devices requires a version of iTunes to be installed on the computer.